# Display a (Synopse) SQLite3 table-column in a Delphi7 TListView

Tags: database, delphi, sqlite

I would like to take the following unit (DrivesData) and display the drive column in a TListView.  I've never worked with the (Synopse) SQLite3 code before so I'm hoping someone could give me a little push in the right direction.

Just add the DrivesData unit to the uses clause then run and it will create the "drives.sqlite" database file with a list of drives 'A' to 'Z'.

```
unit DrivesData;

interface

uses
  SynCommons, SQLite3Commons;

type
  TDrives = class(TSQLRecord)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FDrive: RawUTF8;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    FDrivesModel: TSQLModel;
    FDrivesDatabase: TSQLRest;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(); override;
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property Drive: RawUTF8 read FDrive write FDrive;
  end;

var
  DriveRecord: TDrives;

implementation

uses
  SQLite3;

function CreateDrivesModel(): TSQLModel;
begin
  Result := TSQLModel.Create([TDrives]);
end;

{ TDrives }
constructor TDrives.Create();
var
  X: Char;
begin
  inherited Create();

  FDrivesModel := CreateDrivesModel();
  FDrivesDatabase := TSQLRestServerDB.Create(FDrivesModel, 'drives.sqlite');

  TSQLRestServerDB(FDrivesDatabase).DB.Execute(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS drives ' +
    '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, drive TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE COLLATE NOCASE);');

  for X := 'A' to 'Z' do
  begin
    TSQLRestServerDB(FDrivesDatabase).DB.Execute(
      'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO drives (drive) VALUES ("' + X + ':")');
  end;
end;

destructor TDrives.Destroy();
begin
  if Assigned(FDrivesDatabase) then
    FDrivesDatabase.Free();

  if Assigned(FDrivesModel) then
    FDrivesModel.Free();

  inherited Destroy();
end;

initialization
  DriveRecord := TDrives.Create();

finalization
  if Assigned(DriveRecord) then
    DriveRecord.Free();

end.
```

Comment: Instead of adding 26 entries in a table, why not just add 26 items directly to a list view? Why involve a database at all?

Comment: Why? Basically, for educational purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice try!

But I'm afraid you are missing some points of the framework:

- for instance you're mixing record level and MVC application level: a `TSQLRecord` maps a DB table and you should not declare MVC `TSQLModel` and `TSQLRest` inside this class;
- and you're missing the ORM approach, you don't need to write all those SQL code (the CREATE TABLE and the INSERT): the framework will write it for you, with no error, and the exact expected column type (with collations)!

Instead of using a `TSQLRestServerDB` directly by itself, you should better use a `TSQLRestClientDB` (which will instantiate its privately owned `TSQLRestServerDB`), even if you are still working locally. So you'll get a lot more features with no performance penalty.

You are using a `Char` type in your code. Our framework is UTF-8 oriented, so you should use AnsiChar instead, or use `StringToUtf8()` function to ensure correctness (at least with Unicode version of Delphi).

I'll recommend that you take a look at the sample code source code and the [provided documentation](http://synopse.info/files/pdf/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.pdf) (especially the SAD document, in the general presentation in the first pages, including the SynFile main demo).

To retrieve some data, then display it in the VCL (e.g. in a `TListBox`), take a look at the `TSQLTableJSON` class. There are some code sample in the SAD document (take a look at the keyword index, at the beginning of the document, if you're a bit lost).

Perhaps StackOverflow is not the best place to ask such specific questions. You have our forum available at http://synopse.info to post any questions regarding this framework. You can post your code here.

Thanks for your interest!

Comment: I've written some more correct code in the forum, following your purpose.